How to get context.modules for vite react ssr-manifest.json
The manifest contains mappings of module IDs to their associated chunks and asset files.
I did't find context.modules for vite react ssr. The @vitejs/plugin-vue supports it for vue. What about the @vitejs/plugin-react?
Is there a vite plugin which supports context.modules for react SSR ?

I added a plugin to obtain module dependencies

rollup-plugin-visualizer


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm building exactly this because vite doesn't support preloading lazy loaded modules or CSS chunks in an application full of React.lazy() pages.
It's based of the regular manifest.json because it contains the proper import mappings which ssr-manifest.json does not.
https://github.com/wille/vite-preload
